# Is the hypothesis in this theorem too strict(group-theory)

Tags: group-theory

Please take a look at this theorem:
[image]

This theorem is from the **sixth** edition of a book. In the updated version, in the **seventh** edition then he have included that $K'$ is a subgroup of $G' \cap \phi[G]$. But why did he update it like that? Isn't the correct version in the sixth edition, $K'$ does not have to be a subgroup of $\phi[G]$ for the theorem to be true?
.

Comment: Hmm.... $G$ and $G'$ aren't defined in this question. If $G'$ is the target of $\phi$, then $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of $G'$ and so $G' \cap \phi[G] = G'$. If $G'$ means something different, then I don't know.

Comment: @hunter I update the picture.

Comment: @hunter $\phi$ is a homomorhpism, not an isomorphism, so we do not know that $G'\cap\phi[G]=G'$?

Comment: sorry, I meant = $\phi[G]$ on the right hand side! thanks for updating the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update does not change anything; certainly, it is unnecessary, but it is also not really weakening the theorem. The proof given does, in fact, establish that $\phi^{-1}[K']$ is a subgroup of $G$. However, it is worth noting that the new statement is equivalent, since $K'\cap \phi[G]$ is a subgroup of $G'$ as well, which is contained in the image $\phi[G]$ and has that
$$\phi^{-1}[K']=\phi^{-1}[K'\cap \phi[G]]$$

Comment: Does this still hold of $\phi$ is an homomorphism and not an isomorphism? Because then $K'$ may not be $K'\cap \phi[G]$?

Comment: $K'$ may not equal $K'\cap \phi[G]$, but $\phi^{-1}[K']=\phi^{-1}[K'\cap\phi[G]]$ since, for any set $S$ and function $f:A\rightarrow B$ we have $f^{-1}[S\cap f[A]]=f^{-1}[S]$.

Comment: Thank you, but why do you mean it is not a wakening? Because if $K'$ is a subgroup of $G'$, but not a subgroup of $\phi[G]$, then we can't use the updated theorem, and hence it is weakened?

Comment: @user119615 Well, it's *slightly* weakened, but you could read my post as using the later statement to prove the earlier one; that is, if $K'\cap \phi[G]$ is a subgroup of $G'\cap \phi[G]$, by the later statement $\phi^{-1}[K'\cap \phi[G]]$ is a subgroup of $G$. However $\phi^{-1}[K'\cap\phi[G]]=\phi^{-1}[K']$, so $\phi^{-1}[K']$ is a subgroup of $G$. It's a silly distinction for the author to have made - they added a hypothesis which is easily eliminated altogether and would never be necessary in the proof.

Comment: Oh, sorry I am a little slow. Now I see what you did, we have easily sixth edition -> seventh edition, and you showed easily how seventh edition -> sixth edition.

Answer (score 0):

The original statement is correct (as per the proof). The restriction is not required